# WebGL shader compilation error - optimization did not converge

Tags: windows, webgl, shader, angle

Recently I started to see these errors when compiling shaders. The shaders work, but there is a huge lag spikes when these warnings are displayed. And it's happening randomly with the same shader. Almost like the resources are busy with other things so the optimization times out.

```
WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(52)] : compileToBinary(256): internal warning: optimization did not converge
```

Any idea how to dive deeper into the root cause of the warning? No other compile-warnings are shown at the same time.

Comment: This might be a graphics driver issue, try upgrading your drivers and / or test on a different system.

Comment: I checked the angle implementation of [compileToBinary](https://github.com/google/angle/blob/ec1fe5b743599d4e19da511e20f44c286f4118a0/src/libANGLE/renderer/d3d/HLSLCompiler.cpp) which in turn calls windows [D3DCompile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcompiler/nf-d3dcompiler-d3dcompile) which leads us straight into closed-source territory. You can try to review the transpiled HLSL code using the [WEBGL_debug_shaders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_debug_shaders/getTranslatedShaderSource) extension to check for any problems with the generated code.

Comment: Thanks! I have inspected the HLSL result and could not see anything strange, but the shader works visually after the warning and spike, so I wonder if the translator first try to optimize, then fails (or timeout), and returns to a unoptimised version. And I can only inspect the final version.

Comment: As the ANGLE codebase does not contain any such error message I think the message is coming from the shader compiler within the graphics driver, so the HLSL you see is what causes the issue, that said I'd think that it's very likely that you can't see the issue because it arises from the ast'ed and partly optimized code within the driver that looks nothing like the input string anymore.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, good to know the error message is not coming from ANGLE. It's strange though that it's not happening every time. Maybe I can use the generated hlsl outside webgl and reproduce it and comment away parts to isolate the problematic lines.

Comment: Seems like a viable approach to me, would be interested to hear what you find out.